# Open a CSV file from S3 using Roo on Heroku

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I'm putting together a rake task to grab a CSV file stored on S3 and do some processing on it. I use Roo to process the files. The product is running on Heroku so I do not have local storage for physical files.

The CSV processing I am running works perfectly from the website if I upload the file.

rake task looks like this if I upload just the contents of the file:

```
desc "Checks uploads bucket on S3 and processes for imports"
task s3_import: [:environment] do
    # depends on the environemtn task to load dev/prod env first

    # get an s3 connection
    s3 = AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

    # get the uploads bucket
    bucket = s3.buckets[ENV['UPLOAD_BUCKET']]

    # check each object in the bucket
    bucket.objects.each do |obj|
        #uri = obj.url_for(:read)
        #puts uri
        puts obj.key
        file = obj.read
        User.import(file)
    end

end
```

I have also tried passing just the url to the object but this does not work either.

Basically, when uploading through the page this works to open the files:

```
Roo::Csv.new(file.path)
```

So, I can get the URL of the file, and I can also get the contents of the file into a variable, but I can't work out how to get Roo to open it without a physical file on disk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a CSV file from a stream using Roo in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177382/read-a-csv-file-from-a-stream-using-roo-in-rails-4)

Comment: I've the similar problem, any updates ?

Comment: check the linked question above - basically, I stopped using Roo. I couldn't figure out how to load it from a stream.